# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:11) about stylus file

Tags: webpack, vue.js, stylus, webpack.config.js

I get bellow error in my browser using Vue.js:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/assets/styles/global.styl
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| html, body {
|   margin: 0
|   padding: 0
 @ ./src/main.js 4:0-37
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

In my `webpack.config.js` -> `module` -> `rules`, this is my config of my `.styl` file:

```
{
    test: /\.styl$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,   
        }
      },
      'stylus-loader'
    ],
  },
```

My code `global.styl` is bellow:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
}

body {
  background-image url("../imgs/01.jpg")
  background-size: cover
  background-position: center
  font: 14px 'Helvetica Neue'
  font-weight: 300
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have configured the `'stylus-loader'` in your `webpack.config.js` module rules, but still get the error.

Thats should be you did not install the `stylus-loader` to your `node_modules`.

install the `stylus` and `stylus-loader`:

```
npm i stylus@>=0.52.4 stylus-loader
```

and restrat `pnm run dev`.